# Regex $1, $2, etc

Tags: php, regex, variables

I've been trying to do some regex operations in PHP, and I'm not very skilled in this area. It seems that when I use a regex function like preg_replace on a string, I can access the regex-replaced strings by some sort of variables named $1, $2, and so on. What is this called and how can I use it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These are known in regex terminology as **backreferences** (more on that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php)). You use them to refer to capture groups (or subpatterns, surrounded by `()`) within your regex or in the replacement string.

An example:

```
/* 
 * Replaces abcd123 with 123abcd, or asdf789 with 789asdf.
 * 
 * The $1 here refers to the capture group ([a-z]+),
 * and the $2 refers to the capture group ([0-9]+).
 */
preg_replace('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', '$2$1', $str);
```

Comment: That helps a lot! But I thought that variables don't expand in single quotes, yet it works when I test it. Why is that?

Comment: As PCRE backreferences, they happen to be denoted by `$`, but have nothing to do with PHP variables. They're seen and replaced by the regex engine, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for providing the correct "term;" I'll probably have to look this up in the future, and this term is useful across all programming languages and environments :)

Comment: That's a Perfect answer, good example and well decribe in very short text.

Answer (score 6):

They are called backreferences and match grouped elements within the regexp.

If you surround a section of the regexp with brackets, then you can refer to it in the replace section (or indeed later in the same regexp, by the backreference which corresponds to its position.

Slash form, or dollar form can be used in replacements:

```
\1, \2 == $1, $2
```