# Replace substring with an elaboration of $1 in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a text containing pseudo-tags, used as placemarks to indicate the presence of HTML elements (i.e a photogallery).

```
some text <gallery src="img/myfolder" /> some other text...
```

My goal is to replace all the occurences of `<gallery>` with an HTML code displaying a photogallery of images included in "img/myfolder".

I've found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534516/regex-1-2-etc). Unfortunately I can't perform the direct replacement as indicated there, because I need to do some elaboration before. I must take the "img/myfolder" substring extracted from the text, do a folder scan (I already have the code to perform it) and finally replace `<gallery>` with something like this

```
<ul>
<li><img src="img/myfolder/image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="img/myfolder/image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="img/myfolder/image3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

where images are extracted from "img/myfolder" scan and are unknown when I invoke the `preg_replace` call. How can I do? Is there an efficient way to perform my goal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word:

```
preg_replace_callback()
```

This function allows you to do some sophisticated substitutions. There is an easy guide here: [preg_replace_callback](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#callback)

**Overview of the Procedure**

A. Step 1: You need to match

```
<gallery src="img/myfolder" />
```

Build a regex pattern `$regex` that matches the whole string and places the path ("img/folder") in Group 1.

For instance:

```
$regex = '%<gallery src="([^"]+)" />%';
```

B. Call `preg_replace_callback` and pass it `$regex`, "replaceGallery" and `$string`

```
$new = preg_replace_callback($regex,"replaceGallery",$string);
```

`replaceGallery($m)` will be your callback function. It will build the intricate substitution you are trying to do.

Now define the function `replaceGallery($m)`. Do not worry about `$m`, this is the parameter that `preg_replace_callback` will automatically pass to the function. Just remember that `$m[0]` will be the whole match. `$m[1]` will be the folder path.

Knowing the folder path `$m[1]`, you can go lookup all the images in the folder. Then you can build your string.

Then return your string.

```
function replaceGallery($m) {
   // Your code here
   // use $m[0] and $m[1]
   return $gallery; 
   }
```

Using `$gallery`, `preg_replace_callback` will replace the entire match with the string you built.

A beautiful function, isn't it?

Comment: Wow! I didn't know the preg_replace_callback function. This does exactly what I need. Great, thanks @zx81!

Comment: @Giorgio Just added some details.